# Configure Jekyll to highlight code on page generation?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, octopress

I'm using github pages for my site.
I generate my pages from markdown to html using the built in Jekyll support.

The built in markdown renderer `rdiscount` does handle tripple backtick codeblocks.
but it just applies the language as a css class on the `<pre>`

What should I do to get Jekyll to highlight code on page generation?

I've also tried to copy all stuff from octopress, but whith no luck, the codeblocks still come out with a css class only.

Comment: Get (install) Pygments. The latests Jekyll versions support this highlighter. The Jekyll documentation explains how.

Comment: I switched to redcarpet as the markdown renderer, that did the trick

Comment: I don't think that is necessary. All of them should understand Liquid tags and Jekyll implements a few for the highlighter.